# how to make responsive image fixed and content should on image with scrollable

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I need to design header in 30% of the screen and from 31% to 100% I need a fixed left sidebar menu. On the right side of sidebar need to fix background image with scroll-able form fields also footer fixed in image.

I tried the code below but the image is not fully showing :

```
                        <div class="container">
                        <div class="row">
                         <div class="col-sm-3 col-md-3" style="margin-top: 150px;">
                    <nav id="navbar-black" class="navbar" role="navigation">

                        <div class="navbar-collapse collapse sidebar-navbar-collapse">

                          <ul class="nav navbar-nav">

                          <li class="dropdown">
                            <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown"> Your Details</a>
                              <ul class="dropdown-menu"> 
                                <li><a href="/">abcd</a></li>
                                <li><a href="/">abcd</a></li>
                                <li><a href="/">abcd</a></li>

                                </ul>
                            </li>

                            <li class="dropdown">
                              <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown"> My details</a>
                              <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                                <li><a href="/"> Degree</a></li>


                              </ul>
                            </li>

                            <li class="dropdown">
                              <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Profession</a>
                              <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                                <li><a href="/"> Employement</a></li>
                                <li><a href="/"> References</a></li>

                              </ul>
                            </li>

                          </ul>
                        </div><!--/.nav-collapse -->

                      </nav>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-sm-9 col-md-9" style="position:fixed;">
                            <img class="img-responsive" src="background.png" id="bg" alt="" style="top: 0;right: 0px;min-width: 75%;position: fixed;padding: 0px;margin-top: 150px;">

                                   <div class="col-sm-6">

                                   content goes here with scroll on right side corner
                                    </div>


                          </div>
                      </div>
                      </div>
```

[Image for clarity](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UTjVK.png)

Thanks in advance

Comment: Have you tried anything so far? Please try something first and post when you are stuck, don't expect someone to do it for you. Please head to [HELP] first.

Comment: We code you just ask ! we here to help. Please provide code ! https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: _"Please give your suggestions"_ - here you go: [ask]

Comment: i have updated my code details,